# ExtrudeBufferGeometry causing rotation of output

Tags: three.js

I am trying to extrude some shapes, however I am finding that after extruding, the output is looking like it has been rotated a bit.

I render the actual shape of the triangle and the extruded shape of the triangle after extruding in negative Z direction. Extruding works fine but there is a change in orientation of the output and it looks rotated.

This also happens when I use a custom curve to extrude along.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/extrude-oxf8v
```

Comment: Any specific reason of using `extrudePath: lineCurve` instead of simply setting `depth: 100`?

Comment: I actually want to to it along a custom spline path (also present as commented code in above link). But was finding the result to be rotating. So reduced the example to a simpler case of extruding only along z direction along a line to debug the issue. Still getting rotation.

Comment: (1) You should be extruding (generally) in the direction of the positive z axis since your shape faces that direction. (2) https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5258. (3) For the future, I'd advise you to use the most recent release of three.js.

Answer (score 2):

I found a trick to handle this,and I have tested some cases it works just fine:

To extrude a any shape from A to B (vector3),while preventing it auto rotating:

1. extrude geomtry using "**depth**" instead of "**extrudePath**"
2. var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
3. mesh.**position**.copy(A)   //positioning it to the start point
4. mesh.**lookAt**(B)   //things done!

Comment: it's 2014 and it's working for me fine. deserves an upvote.