# Rotate Object between two points (Three JS)

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, 3d

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34TpS.png) I am trying to create a mesh that stetches between two other points (or meshes) and can't seem to get past the final hurdle of rotating the stretched mesh to the right location. It seems that I am calculating and placing the mid-point correctly (cube1 + cube2) / 2. My Calculation for rotation is

`let currentDirection = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);`

`let newDirection = endcoords.clone().sub(startcoords).normalize();`

`let rotationAxis = currentDirection.cross(newDirection).normalize();`

`let rotationAngle = Math.acos(currentDirection.dot(newDirection));`

`cube3.rotateOnAxis(rotationAxis,rotationAngle)`

However, this seems to be rotating incorrectly, I'm not sure what I am missing, attact a screenshot of the current result.

I have tried cube3.rotateOnWorldAxis as well but that seems to not change anything.

[Here is a gif of the scene with the camera rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJZeJ.gif)
I am aiming for the red cube (scaled), to be rotated in a way that it reaches from the red cube to the blue

Comment: Can you show, at least, what should rotate around what, with gif or arrows?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz Sure I have added a gif of the scene and an explanation to the end of the question.
here is the gif: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJZeJ.gif

Comment: paste your sample code on jsfiddle or codesandbox woud be helpful for others to review your question.Besides, three.js's extrudeGeometry may suit your need. see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893003/extrudebuffergeometry-causing-rotation-of-output/70706913#70706913